# How to check if the string is contained in custom alphabet?

Tags: javascript, regex

i would like to write a function like this

```
let string = "s4D$XLssksXKKLX";

//this alphabet is in array, but i can convert to other
let alphabet = [s4L1Xl7CbKrTD8Uo_NPdVWiI9zpBfZMm20hJ$qA5kuQta36yFevxnYHcEGRjgwSO]

if (string is contained in alphabet)
   return true
else
   return false
```

can someone help me?

thank you guys!

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "the string is contained"... exactly matching part of an item inside the array? Or just all the same characters are in both?

Comment: i mean this, for example the string s4D$XLssksXKKLX match with my custom alphabet, instead the string s4D@XLssksXKKLX with the @ character don't match with the alphabet. I'm sorry for my bad English, I answered you?

Comment: Your alphabet contains duplicate letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this regEx

```
(text).match(/^([s4L1Xl7CbKrTD8Uo_NPdVWiI9zpBfZMm20hJ$qA5kuQta36yFevxnYHcEGRjgwSO])+$/g))
```

in this way, the string of any size must belong to this custom alphabet :)

Answer (score 1):

The **[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** string method does exactly this:

```js
let alphabet = "s4L1Xl7CbKrTD8Uo_NPdVWiI9zpBfZMm20hJ$qA5kuQta36yFevxnYHcEGRjgwSO";

function testString(input){
  if (alphabet.indexOf(input) > -1){
     return true;
  } else {
     return false ;
  } 
}

console.log(testString("s4D$XLssksXKKLX"));
console.log(testString("CbKrTD8U"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a string utility method called indexOf. You can refer to this [stackoverflow post] :[How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

With [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) you can use [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method that determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate:

```js
let alphabet = 's4L1Xl7CbKrTD8Uo_NPdVWiI9zpBfZMm20hJ$qA5kuQta36yFevxnYHcEGRjgwSO';

console.log(alphabet.includes('s4D$XLssksXKKLX'));
console.log(alphabet.includes('0hJ$qA5k'));
```

Comment: thank you yosvel, but in my idea, both string 0hJ$qA5k and sssssssss, belong to the alphabet. the string that not belong to the alphabet is for example 0hJ@qA5k. I managed to explain to me? Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: thank you Yosvel, but why if have this string s4D$XLssksXKKLX the function return false, instead of true?

Comment: I have added an example `alphabet.includes('s4D$XLssksXKKLX')` and it logs is `false` because the string `s4D$XLssksXKKLX` is not included in the `alphabet` variable